# PMD maven plugin: How to specify a different ruleset for tests?

Tags: maven, static-analysis, pmd, software-quality

I need to configure the PMD maven plugin to scan test source code with less strict checks comparing to production code.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to configure two separate [executions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_executions_Tag) for the plugin. This allows you to use different configurations. Once execution checks only production code (`<includeTests>false</includeTests>`) and the other checks test-code only (`<includeTests>true</includeTests>` and `<excludeRoots><excludeRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java</excludeRoot></excludeRoots>`).

If you share your solution, we can add it as an example on https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/

Another way to do it is to use the same code quality rules for all your code, avoiding to make compromises because it's "just test code". While test code doesn't run in production, it's used to test production code, so you might consider the test code then as your weakest link if you use less strict checks...

---

Here's the complete plugin configuration for this scenario:

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.14.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includeTests>false</includeTests>
                    <rulesets>
                        <ruleset>config/pmd/pmdMain.xml</ruleset>
                    </rulesets>
                    <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pmd-main</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pmd-test</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>pmd</goal>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <targetDirectory>${project.build.directory}/pmdTest/</targetDirectory>
                            <includeTests>true</includeTests>
                            <excludeRoots>
                                <excludeRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java</excludeRoot>
                            </excludeRoots>
                            <rulesets>
                                <ruleset>config/pmd/pmdTest.xml</ruleset>
                            </rulesets>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>cpd</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>cpd-check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

It uses the ruleset `config/pmd/pmdMain.xml` for the main code without tests. This is configured directly at the plugin level.
The ruleset `config/pmd/pmdTest.xml` is used for the test code only. This is configured in the execution with id `pmd-test`.

It has one downside though: PMD is run three times.... twice for the main code, and once for the test code. The reason is that "pmd:check" triggers automatically "pmd:pmd", but it uses only the standard configuration (e.g. ignored the lifecycle/execution id).

The execution "pmd-test" calls once "pmd:pmd" for the test code (which creates target/pmdTest/pmd.xml), then calls pmd:check - which itself calls pmd:pmd and uses the default configuration - and then runs pmd:check actually, which uses the execution configuration and uses target/pmdTest/pmd.xml to decide whether to fail the build.